# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync request

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to send an Object as part of httprequest. The values are populated from Specflow table.

```
public class Request
{
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> RequestParameters = 
                                                    new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    public void setRequestParameters(Table table)
    {

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestParameters.Add(row[0], row[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

Request request = new Request();
request.setRequestParameters(table);
var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Request>(_address.ToString(), request).Result;
```

The value is sent however I don't want the memberName(RequestParameters) enclosing the values. Is there a way to ignore it?

```
{
   "RequestParameters":{  
      "InitialCashAmount":"10000.00",
      "TransferAmount":"5000.00",
      "PersonalRegularContribution":"100.00"
   }
}
```

Comment: What if you pass request.RequestParameters instead of request itself to PostAsJsonAsync? Do you see any difference?

Comment: Any reason you're using `dynamic` instead of `object`?

Comment: @Yuval: The plan is to take different key,values and values could be any data type. However just realized Specflow passes in all table values as Strings so this solution wont work. 
e.g. Given I have following values
|FieldKey|FieldValue|
|InitialAmount|1000.00|
|Currency|"GBP"|

Comment: You'll need to parse out the values beforehand than.

Answer (score 0):

Use **request.RequestParameters**

```
var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(_address.ToString(), request.RequestParameters).Result;
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error Error 4 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'PostAsJsonAsync' and the best extension method overload 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, string, T)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 5 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,dynamic>' to 'Go.RequestBuilders.Request' C:\AcceptanceTestSteps\ServiceCallSteps.cs

Comment: @DesertRose You need : PostAsJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(...) instead?

Comment: @Ram: Thanks for your soln.